# Encoding in tuple Python

Tags: python, utf-8, tuples, decode, encode

I have an array containing SQL query result. I need to convert this array in tuple to make a request like this:

```
t = tuple(data)
querysring="INSERT INTO %s VALUES %s "%(table,t)
cur.execute(querysring)
```

But my array contains values like ['François','données'] and when I convert this in tuple it's make and insert 'Fran\xc3\xa7ois' in my database.

I have try to decode and encode (utf-8) but it seem not working.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: So what do you *actually* want to insert into the database?

Comment: What sort of RDBMS are you working with? What sort of field are you tring to insert into? What do you *expect* to insert?

Comment: I use Postgresql. And I want to insert someting like this: "Insert Into AGENT values ("bock","François","Individual"). But it make that:   "Insert Into AGENT values ("bock","Fran\xc3\xa7ois","Individual")

Comment: All fields are String fields

Comment: Are you in Python 3 or 2?

Comment: I currently use Python 3 but I can use Python 2