# Decode a string: Python

Tags: python, utf-8, decode, encode

I built a string with a tuple like this:

```
t = tuple(data)
querysring="INSERT INTO %s VALUES %s "%(table,t)
```

When I print the string the result is:

```
INSERT INTO AGENT VALUES ('Bock', 'Fran\\xc3\\xa7ois Bock', 'Individual', 'fb****@mail.com')
```

But I want something like this:

```
 INSERT INTO AGENT VALUES ('Bock', 'François Bock', 'Individual', 'fb****@mail.com')
```

It is possible to decode the string ?
I'm using Python2.x but I can use Python3.x

I try this:

```
querysring=u"INSERT INTO %s VALUES %s "%(table,t)
print(ftfy.fix_text(querysring))
```

But it's not working

Comment: I'm not sure how this question differs significantly from your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43629059/encoding-in-tuple-python. Also, you shouldn't be using Python string formatting to generate your query, you should have parameterised queries, which may itself fix your issue.

Comment: Yes but how can I make it ? I don't know the numbers values there is in my tuple(data)

Comment: With python2 put `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` into your first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is superficial and related to how `print` displays lists and list items differently. The printed output of a list is in `ascii` even if the items *within* the list are correctly encoded in `utf-8`. First, using [`chardet`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) library:

```
from chardet.universaldetector import UniversalDetector

a = ['Bock', 'François Bock']

detector = UniversalDetector()
detector.feed(str(a))
detector.close()

print "Encoding for the str(list): ", detector.result

detector = UniversalDetector()
detector.feed(a[1])
detector.close()

print "Encoding for list[1]:       ", detector.result

print "The whole list:             ", a
print "Item in list:               ", a[1]
```

Aside from the off-putting printouts, it's possible to still write to the database with the correct encoding with a parameterized query. The last part of the below code writes to a file to confirm that the data encoding is preserved:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
conn.text_factory = str
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testing(test1 TEXT, test2 TEXT)")
conn.commit()

my_tuple = 'Bock', 'François Bock'
table = 'testing'

placeholders = ', '.join('?' for item in my_tuple)
query = "INSERT INTO {} VALUES ({})".format(table, placeholders)

c.execute(query, my_tuple)

c.execute("SELECT * FROM testing")
all_data = c.fetchone()

# Check the printouts
print all_data
print all_data[1]

# For good measure, write them to a file
with open('check_output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(', '.join(item for item in all_data))
```

Comment: Thank you for you help and your explanation. I use psycopg2, so the parameterized query is a bit different but it's really help me !

Comment: @FrancoisBock you're welcome, is it `%s` instead of `?`? Either way, don't use string formatting, that leaves you open to SQL injection.

Comment: Yes that's it " '%s' "